# How to get quantiles to work with summarise_at and group_by (dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr, quantile

When using `dplyr` to create a table of summary statistics that is organized by levels of a variable, I cannot figure out the syntax for calculating quartiles without having to repeat the column name. That is, using calls, such as `vars()` and `list()` work with other functions, such as `mean()` and `median()` but not with `quantile()`

Searches have produced antiquated solutions that no longer work because they use deprecated calls, such as `do()` and/or `funs()`.

```
data(iris)
library(tidyverse)

#This works: Notice I have not attempted to calculate quartiles yet
summary_stat <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(Sepal.Length), 
               list(min=min, median=median, max=max,
               mean=mean, sd=sd)
               )
A tibble: 3 x 6
  Species      min median   max  mean    sd
  <fct>      <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 setosa       4.3    5     5.8  5.01 0.352
2 versicolor   4.9    5.9   7    5.94 0.516
3 virginica    4.9    6.5   7.9  6.59 0.636

##########################################################################
#Does NOT work:
five_number_summary <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(Sepal.Length),
               list(min=min, Q1=quantile(.,probs = 0.25),
                    median=median, Q3=quantile(., probs = 0.75),
                    max=max))

Error: Must use a vector in `[`, not an object of class matrix.
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace

###########################################################################
#This works: Remove the vars() argument, remove the list() argument,
  #replace summarise_at() with summarise()
  #but the code requires repeating the column name (Sepal.Length)

five_number_summary <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(min=min(Sepal.Length), 
            Q1=quantile(Sepal.Length,probs = 0.25),
            median=median(Sepal.Length), 
            Q3=quantile(Sepal.Length, probs = 0.75),
            max=max(Sepal.Length))

# A tibble: 3 x 6
  Species      min    Q1 median    Q3   max
  <fct>      <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 setosa       4.3  4.8     5     5.2   5.8
2 versicolor   4.9  5.6     5.9   6.3   7  
3 virginica    4.9  6.22    6.5   6.9   7.9
```

This last piece of code produces exactly what I am looking for, but I am wondering why there isn't a shorter syntax that doesn't force me to repeat the variable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're missing the `~` in front of the `quantile` function in the `summarise_at` call that failed. Try the following:

```
five_number_summary <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(Sepal.Length),
               list(min=min, Q1=~quantile(., probs = 0.25),
                    median=median, Q3=~quantile(., probs = 0.75),
                    max=max))
five_number_summary
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  Species      min    Q1 median    Q3   max
  <fct>      <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 setosa       4.3  4.8     5     5.2   5.8
2 versicolor   4.9  5.6     5.9   6.3   7  
3 virginica    4.9  6.22    6.5   6.9   7.9
```

Comment: Thank you @Arienrhod. What is the significance of the `~`? Why does only the `quantile()` function need the `~` but not other functions?

Comment: As far as I know the `~` is shorthand for `function(x){...}`. Without it, R tries to evaluate the expression `quantile...` which fails in this context. The `~` is used often in `purrr` functions and you can find some more info [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise_all.html) and [here](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html).

Answer (score 14):

You can create a data frame / tibble within `summarise` which is then spliced into separate columns.

```r
library(tidyverse)

iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(as_tibble_row(quantile(Sepal.Length)))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   Species     `0%` `25%` `50%` `75%` `100%`
#>   <fct>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 setosa       4.3  4.8    5     5.2    5.8
#> 2 versicolor   4.9  5.6    5.9   6.3    7  
#> 3 virginica    4.9  6.22   6.5   6.9    7.9

# with .name_repair
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(as_tibble_row(quantile(Sepal.Length), .name_repair = \(x) paste0('q', parse_number(x))))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   Species       q0   q25   q50   q75  q100
#>   <fct>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 setosa       4.3  4.8    5     5.2   5.8
#> 2 versicolor   4.9  5.6    5.9   6.3   7  
#> 3 virginica    4.9  6.22   6.5   6.9   7.9
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

You can create a list column and then use `unnest_wider`, which requires tidyr 1.0.0

```
library(tidyverse)

iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(q = list(quantile(Sepal.Length))) %>% 
  unnest_wider(q)

# # A tibble: 3 x 6
#   Species     `0%` `25%` `50%` `75%` `100%`
#   <fct>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 setosa       4.3  4.8    5     5.2    5.8
# 2 versicolor   4.9  5.6    5.9   6.3    7  
# 3 virginica    4.9  6.22   6.5   6.9    7.9
```

There's a `names_repair` argument, but apparently that changes the name of all the columns, and not just the ones being unnested (??)

```
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(q = list(quantile(Sepal.Length))) %>% 
  unnest_wider(q, names_repair = ~paste0('Q_', sub('%', '', .)))

# # A tibble: 3 x 6
#   Q_Species    Q_0  Q_25  Q_50  Q_75 Q_100
#   <fct>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 setosa       4.3  4.8    5     5.2   5.8
# 2 versicolor   4.9  5.6    5.9   6.3   7  
# 3 virginica    4.9  6.22   6.5   6.9   7.9
```

Another option is `group_modify`

```
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  group_modify(~as.data.frame(t(quantile(.$Sepal.Length))))

# # A tibble: 3 x 6
# # Groups:   Species [3]
#   Species     `0%` `25%` `50%` `75%` `100%`
#   <fct>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 setosa       4.3  4.8    5     5.2    5.8
# 2 versicolor   4.9  5.6    5.9   6.3    7  
# 3 virginica    4.9  6.22   6.5   6.9    7.9
```

Or you could use data.table

```
library(data.table)
irisdt <- as.data.table(iris)

irisdt[, as.list(quantile(Sepal.Length)), Species]
#       Species  0%   25% 50% 75% 100%
# 1:     setosa 4.3 4.800 5.0 5.2  5.8
# 2: versicolor 4.9 5.600 5.9 6.3  7.0
# 3:  virginica 4.9 6.225 6.5 6.9  7.9
```

Answer (score 3):

A note about a more up-to-date version of @arienrhod

```r
library(dplyr,quietly = TRUE,verbose = FALSE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
five_number_summary <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(across(Sepal.Length, list(min=min, Q1=~quantile(., probs = 0.25),
                    median=median, Q3=~quantile(., probs = 0.75),
                    max=max),  .names = "{.fn}"))
five_number_summary
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>   Species      min    Q1 median    Q3   max
#>   <fct>      <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 setosa       4.3  4.8     5     5.2   5.8
#> 2 versicolor   4.9  5.6     5.9   6.3   7  
#> 3 virginica    4.9  6.22    6.5   6.9   7.9
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>